# Select value and text both from DataGridViewComboBoxColumn c#

Tags: c#

suppose i have one datagridview and datagridview has one DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.
i have populate datagridview combobox column with country name and code.

so now i want that when i am reading datagridview cell value in for loop then i want get DataGridViewComboBoxColumn selected value and text. i could not get the value but not being able to get display text from DataGridViewComboBoxColumn in for loop.

if it is possible then plzz help me with small code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= dgList.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = dgList.Rows[i].Cells[0] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
            int index = cell == null || cell.Value == null ? -1 : cell.Items.IndexOf(cell.Value);
            string strVal = cell.Value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

thanks

Comment: How are you binding the values to the combobox column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try accessing the values like `FormattedValue` and `Value`, this should give you the two values.

I had tried using a `Dictionary<string,string>` as `DataSource` and using the above properties i was able to get both the values.

Comment: thanks FormattedValue giving the text and Value is giving the value. it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dgList.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        { 
       string strval=((ComboBox)(dgList.Rows[i].cells[0].FindControl("ComboBox1"))).SelectedValue;
        }
```

Comment: i am not talking about asp.net. i am working with windows application with c#. so there i am working with datagridview. FindControl not there. did u test ur code in win apps.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just cast the value to the expected type?

Try this:

dgList["columnName", RowIndex].Value

For example

Convert.toInt32(dgList["columnName", RowIndex].Value)